# Ubuntu 16 graphical login not working but terminal working

Tags: 16.04, apt, login, lightdm

I have suffering problems last few days. When I try to logo on Ubuntu 16 by graphics, I can't log on to the system.But I can log on by terminal. I searched through internet for this problems but I can't find Solution

**Steps I have done so far:**

1. remove .Xauthority files
2. Reinstall Ubuntu desktop
3. sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
4. sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
5. restart lightdm

I couldn't find solution by doing all of this steps

---

## After running `upstart` I got following error:

```
upstart:error while loading shared libraries: libnih.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

### **After running `systemd` I got following errors**

```
Trying to run as user interface, but $xdg_runtime_dir not set
```

### **My `Xsession-errors` file have following lines**

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or library
cannot connect to brltty at: 0
/sbin/upstart: error while loading shared libaries: libnih.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Please [edit] and describe what you did prior to noticing the problem. Perhaps something that explains why you're getting an `upstart` error in Ubuntu 16.04 that should be running `systemd`?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: It will be much easier to troubleshoot this problem in a graphical interface. Can you add a new user then log in as that user? To do that run **sudo adduser test** then follow the prompts (you can just press enter for the default answer).  Add the user to the sudo group: **sudo usermod -aG sudo test** and then try to log in the graphical interface as test.

Comment: I created new user but I can't log on to the system by using GUI. Also guest user GUI log in not working

Comment: What happens when you try to log into the GUI?

Comment: After entering password, then it splash black screen some seconds and then redirects me again to login screen